# Symfony2 FOSuserbundle and ntlm authentication

Tags: php, symfony, ntlm, fosuserbundle

How setup support ntlm authentication for FOSUserbundle?
I have in my mysql database list of all accetable users for site, and i need check is user that authorized by ntlm guest, or verifed user(exists in table of users).

Answer (score 0):

This page from the documentation should give you everything you need on implementing your own listener: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

Some more links and information is given in this related question: [Symfony2: automatically logging in users from their Windows session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811280/symfony2-automatically-logging-in-users-from-their-windows-session/17331193#17331193)

It seems there is no NTLM bundle available, so you will have to write something yourself.

Good luck!