# Symfony2: automatically logging in users from their Windows session

Tags: windows, symfony, authentication, ntlm

In `Symfony2` I have built an intranet. It currently uses the `FOSUserBundle` and an `LDAP bundle` to log users in, and I would like to add the functionality to log in user from their session in Windows.

I found [an NTLM script](http://siphon9.net/loune/2007/10/simple-lightweight-ntlm-in-php/) for PHP and [an updated version](http://siphon9.net/loune/2010/11/php-ntlm-now-working-with-lighttpdfastcgi/) of it, but I haven't been able to incorporate them into Symfony2.

I also found [an NTLM bundle for Symfony2](https://github.com/ecoad/NtlmBundle), but it was written for an older version of Symfony and it is not maintained anymore. I was unable to rewrite it and get it to work.

My question is; how could I automatically log in users from their Windows session in my Symfony2-app, in addition to the already present `LDAP` functionality? What would be the best and easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the classes in the `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall` folder.

You should also read this thread with some more useful information on implementing your own AuthenticationListener: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony-devs/oSUqDyMsZpI

This page from the documentation should give you everything you need on implementing your own listener: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html